# How to disable Rails web dyno on Heroku via Procfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, scheduled-tasks, procfile

I have a little doubt about Heroku procfiles and Rails. Before you ask, I'm currently using **Ruby 2.1.2** and **Rails 4.1.6**.

My project will only run Schedule Tasks via [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#installing-the-add-on) - in other words, I don't want pay to run a website that actually doesn't exists and a simple Rake Task that will execute every **X minutes**.

**Currently my procfile is the following:**

```
web:
```

But Heroku is still running the web dyno, as you can see when I run `heroku ps` on my Terminal:

```
=== web (1X): `bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV`
web.1: up 2015/01/23 10:04:31 (~ 27m ago)
```

Then, I have two questions (focus on the second one):

1. If my "web dyno" still run alongside my scheduled tasks via Heroku Scheduler, I will exceed 750 free hours from Heroku?
2. **How can I disable the web dyno using a Procfile?**

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the web dyno via Heroku Web UI: Resources -  Dynos [Edit], toggle off Web (and probably toggle Scheduler on), then Save. Or command line: `heroku ps:scale web=0`.

This will remain on subsequent deploys, so Procfile defines how to run dynos, and the Heroku settings define which dynos to run, and how many.